# Flet doesn't see python libraries

Tags: python, user-interface, flet

I'm trying to create a social network in python flet. I wrote a bunch of code and decided to compile it all into a static website. So, flet does not see other libraries besides flet (I know that they must be specified in requirements.txt). Help me please! I use the library (for the database) boto3.

I tried to fix it via micropip, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you add all the module to requirements.txt then the possible bug may be the network if you see "If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled." in the console (It is in the chrome dev tools). You have to change your user agent for requesting data and change the mode to 'no-cors'.

I encountered an internet error which is i can't get data from localhost due the pyodide but i change the user agent and reboot the pc and then it magically starts to work :D

### And if it doesn't work can you provide some information from the console